# I cannot cancel my thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

I am developing an app that communicated with Arduino via bluetooth, however, I dont know why I cannot cancel the thread which responsible for the bluetooth inputstream.

```
public class mainclass extends Activity{
 BluetoothSocket scSocket = AnotherClass.btSocket;
 SendReceiveBytes  sendReceiveBT;
 Thread th;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         .
         .
         sendReceiveBT = new SendReceiveBytes(scSocket);
         th = new Thread(sendReceiveBT);
         th.start();
         .
         .
         sendReceiveBT.stop=true;
         Log.e(TAG, "Request sent");
         .
         .
       }
 }

public class SendReceiveBytes implements Runnable {
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
String readMessage="";

 private  BluetoothSocket btSocket;
 private InputStream btInputStream = null;
 private OutputStream btOutputStream = null;
 public boolean stop=false;
 public boolean stopped=false;
 String TAG = "SendReceiveBytes";

 public SendReceiveBytes(BluetoothSocket socket) {
 btSocket = socket;
 try {
 btInputStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
 btOutputStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
 } 
 catch (IOException streamError) { 
 Log.e(TAG, "Error when getting input or output Stream");
 }
 }

 public void run() {
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer store for the stream
 int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

 // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
 while (!stop) {
 try {
 // Read from the InputStream
 bytes = btInputStream.read(buffer);
 // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
 byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) buffer;
 // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
 readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, bytes);
 } 
 catch (IOException e) {
 Log.e(TAG, "Error reading from btInputStream");
 break;
 }
 }
 Log.e(TAG, "Quit");
 stopped=true;
 }

}
```

In the LogCat, the tag with "Request sent" is shown which means I already set the "stop" to true, however, the tag with "Quit" never show up.

Comment: This method is deprecated  in Android

Answer (score 0):

You could try to override the stop()-method, which set stop-flag to true. Also make sure to close your streams.